# Displaying colorbar tick labels with scientific notation in xarray contourf plot

Tags: python-xarray, colorbar

With xarray contourf plotting, the colorbar is created automatically, and for very large numbers it gives scientific notation (i.e. 1e8) for the tick labels. I would though like to obtain this also for slighly smaller numbers (e.g. 1e4). How can I do this? Is there a way through the cbar_kwargs argument perhaps?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi there, I had the same question recently and couldn't find a satisfying answer, but I found something which will do until I find how to get the colorbar handle from xarray. So, `import matplotlib as mpl` and then change the rules for the exponent style globally `mpl.rcParams["axes.formatter.limits"] = [-1, 6]`. [Default is `[-5,6]`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter.set_powerlimits)